# Using Table name in vlookup for conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting, vlookup, named-ranges

I have some cells which I would like to format to display the level achieved for each person:
[image]

On the right I have a table called Table3 which contains the data of the level achieved by each person. This is shown on the left by a bar graph.

The formula I have in B2 to give me the TRUE and FALSEs for the conditional formatting is: `=VLOOKUP($A2,Table3,2,FALSE)>=B$1`. However, if copy and paste this formula into the conditional formatting dialogue box I get an error saying the formula is not valid. If I however replace `Table3` with `$G$2:$H$5` it works perfectly.

So, why does conditional formatting not like my table names, and is there a way to use tables when doing conditional formatting?

Comment: Do you have any hiding rows or filter in Table3? if it is normal no filter no hidden rows it worked with me

Comment: I don't have anything hidden or filtered in by workbook

Comment: I just looked at this again and it appears to be problem with using table names, not named ranges. I have amended by question to specifically ask about table ranges.

Comment: If Table3 is not a named range then you have to write sheet!$G$2:$H$5 in Vlookup you cannot just write the name of the sheet only

Comment: use named range instead of sheet name in conditional Formatting

Comment: Yes, but why does a named range work while a table name does not? Why are the two treated differently?

Answer (score 2):

To reference a table within conditional formatting formula you will need to use `INDIRECT("<Table_Name>")`.

Your formula will thus be : `=VLOOKUP($A2,INDIRECT("Table3"),2,FALSE)>=B$1`

I don't know why but it just works.

Reference: [How to use a table name in data validation lists and conditional formatting formulas](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2012/10/15/how-to-use-a-table-name-in-data-validation-lists-and-conditional-formatting-formulas/)

(BTW:  Why don't you just use the "Data Bar" Conditional Formatting in your table?  It would be much easier.)